# numpy: efficient way to do "any" or "all" on the result of an operation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose that you have two NumPy arrays, `a` and `b`, and you want to test whether any value of `a` is greater than the corresponding value of `b`.

Now you could calculate a boolean array and call its `any` method:

```
(a > b).any()
```

This will do all the looping internally, which is good, but it suffers from the need to perform the comparison on *all* the pairs even if, say, the very first result evaluates as `True`.

Alternatively, you could do an explicit loop over scalar comparisons. An example implementation in the case where `a` and `b` are the same shape (so broadcasting is not required) might look like:

```
any(ai > bi for ai, bi in zip(a.flatten(), b.flatten()))
```

This will benefit from the ability to stop processing after the first `True` result is encountered, but with all the costs associated with an explicit loop in Python (albeit inside a comprehension).

Is there any way, either in NumPy itself or in an external library, that you could pass in a *description* of the operation that you wish to perform, rather than the *result* of that operation, and then have it perform the operation internally (in optimised low-level code) inside an "any" loop that can be broken out from?

One could imagine hypothetically some kind of interface like:

```
from array_operations import GreaterThan, Any

expression1 = GreaterThan('x', 'y')
expression2 = Any(expression1)

print(expression2.evaluate(x=a, y=b))
```

If such a thing exists, clearly it could have other uses beyond efficient evaluation of `all` and `any`, in terms of being able to create functions dynamically.

Is there anything like this?

Comment: Thinking about it further, in my hypothetical interface one would probably actually want something like `GreaterThan(Argument('x'), Argument('y'))` in order to distinguish between an argument name and a string constant.  But you get the general idea.

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve this is with delayed/deferred/lazy evaluation.  The C++ community uses something called "expression templates" to achieve this; you can find an accessible overview here: http://courses.csail.mit.edu/18.337/2015/projects/TylerOlsen/18337_tjolsen_ExpressionTemplates.pdf

In Python the easiest way to do this is using Numba.  You basically just write the function you need in Python using `for` loops, then you decorate it with `@numba.njit` and it's done.  Like this:

```
@numba.njit
def any_greater(a, b):
    for ai, bi in zip(a.flatten(), b.flatten()): 
        if ai > bi: 
            return True 
    return False
```

There is/was a NumPy enhancement proposal that could help your use case, but I don't think it has been implemented: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/neps/deferred-ufunc-evaluation.html

Comment: Lots of interesting info there thanks, especially `numba`.

Comment: @alaniwi: You're welcome.  I tested that `any_greater` implementation now and fixed it so it actually works with Numba exactly as written.